# How to transfer the data from arraylist to JS arraylist (C# webform)

Tags: javascript, c#, arraylist, webforms

```
<body>

    <script>
        var jslist = [];
        function updateList() {
            var arlist1 = <%=arlist1%>;  
            jslist = arlist1;
            document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = jslist;
        }
        window.onload = updateList;
    </script>

    
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
        <p id="demo"></p>
    </form>

</body>



    public partial class JSPassData : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ArrayList arlist1 = new ArrayList()
            {
                1,
                "Bill",
                300,
                4.5f
            };

            var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
            var json = serializer.Serialize(arlist1);

            Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("arlist1", json);
        }
    }
```

Keep showing message about The name 'arlist1' does not exist in the current context (But I have already defined)

Why I can't transfer the contents of an arraylist to JS?

Comment: If I understand RegisterArrayDeclaration correctly (it has been a loooong time), then you would not define the javascript array because the script manager will do it for you. Though, the error message you are getting is a different issue than that but I can't tell what that is by the code you have shown.

Comment: I've been stuck on this problem for days, And no one knows the solution, even chatgpt will not

Comment: arlist1 is defined in the scope of page_load but you are trying to use it outside of that scope to dynamically generate some JavaScript. When you fix that I think there will be more problems with the way you are doing the array in JavaScript

Comment: I've tried putting arlist1 anywhere, but it's still stuck with the error message, and I can't think of any reason why.

Comment: You don't even need to do it anyway. RegisterArrayDeclaration is going to create the JavaScript array for you

Answer (score 0):

Well, from what I can tell, it DOES work!

But, then again, a .net ArrayList is quite old, and has ZERO to do with JavaScript.

If you convert a .net ArrayList to a serlizied ojbect, then you get this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
   var arlist1 =  new Array([1,"Bill",300,4.5]);
    //]]>
</script>
```

So, note sure why the // comments are placed in that.

but look VERY close!!!

we have this:

```
   var arlist1 =  new Array([1,"Bill",300,4.5]);
```

that means we have a array, with element 0 as a array!!!

So, lets put this code on our page:

```
        <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Create the array" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
        <br />
        <asp:Button ID="cmdShow" runat="server" Text="Show Array"
            OnClientClick="showvalues();return false" />

        <script>
            function showvalues() {
                myOut = $('#OutPutArea')
                s = "array count size = "
                s += arlist1[0].length + "<br/>"
                // display all the elements
                s += "============<br/>"
                for (i = 0; i < arlist1[0].length; i++) {
                    s += arlist1[0][i] + "<br/>"
                }
                myOut.html(s)
            }
        </script>
        
        <br />
        <div id="OutPutArea">
        </div>
```

And code behind is this:

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ArrayList myList = new ArrayList()
        {
            1,
            "Bill",
            300,
            4.5f
        };

        var serializer = new JavaScriptSerializer();
        var json = serializer.Serialize(myList);
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterArrayDeclaration("arlist1", json);
    }
```

So, we will click on the first button (to generate the array - server side code).

then we will click on button 2 (cmdShow) that runs client side code, and thus we see/get this:

[image]

So, what you have does seem to work just fine. However, using a ListArray as noted actually serlizes into a js array of one element, and that one element (first element[0]) just turns out to be a array.

I mean, you can have each element of the array as a array (array of array's is perfectly legal here).

Comment: Thank you very, very much, I used almost the same method, and then I did it too!